# Generating in the computer a bi-dimensional vector which components obey a gaussian distribution from a standard random number generator

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm showing you an exercise I have tried and I'm looking for your opinion/critic because this is my first time in kinetic theory and stochastic processes and I wish to know if I'm making right, in other words, can you check it and tell me if everything is fine with my answer?

Greetings!

> Consider two stochastic variables $X,\,Y\,$ defined both in the interval $\,[-\infty,+\infty],\,$ and suppose they obey a bi-dimensional gaussian distribution, i.e.,
>   $$P_{2}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^{2}}e^{-(x^{2}+y^{2})/(2\,\sigma^{2})}$$
>   Now, let's define $\,s=x^{2}+y^{2}\,$  and $\,\phi\,$ the angle formed by the vector of components $(x,y)$ with respect to the positive semi-axis $\,OX\,$ (i.e., the usual polar angle).
>
> Discuss how can be generated in the computer a bi-dimensional vector which components obey a gaussian distribution from a standard random number generator, that gives numbers uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.

What I have done:

Given a standard random number generator. Let $n_{1}, n_{2}$ be the results of two outputs of this number generator. Define $s$ so that:
$$\int_{0}^{s} \frac{e^{-z/2\sigma^{2}}}{2\sigma^{2}}dz=1-e^{-s/2\sigma^{2}}=n_{1}$$
So: $s=2\sigma^{2} ln(|1-n_{1}|).$

$\theta=2\pi n_{2}.$

Let $$x=\sqrt{s}\cos(\theta)$$
    $$y=\sqrt{s}\sin(\theta).$$
The points $(x,y)$ so generated have the prescribed distribution.

Comment: This is a strangely composed question: you obviously have a precise idea about how to generate (x,y), or have been explained how, and yet you say nothing about the reasons why this algorithm should be correct, so much so that it is difficult to guess what you really expect from us. Additionally, some details of your suggestion are frankly sloppy (note that your s is always negative...) hence in the end, the answer to "can you check it and tell me if everything is fine with my answer?" is: No, everything is not fine.

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like the Box-Muller method of generating two independent standard normal random variables $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ from two independent standard uniform random variables $U_1$ and $U_2.$
Please check online sources including Wikipedia, Wolfram, any of several on this site, or lecture notes
from NYU and CalTech--depending on your mathematical level and
whether you are mainly interested in mathematical proofs or 
computer implementations.

Intuitively, the process may be clearest when considered in
reverse. Suppose we have a rifle clamped in a vise and aimed
at the bull's eye of a target. Horizontal errors and vertical
errors $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, respectively are independently $Norm(0,1).$

Upon converting to polar coordinates, it seems clear that,
associated with the position of a random rifle hit, will be an angle $\Theta$ clockwise from the positive half line that is 
distributed $Unif(0, 2\pi)$. It can be divided by $2\pi$ to give
a standard uniform random variable $Unif(0,1).$

The squared distance from the origin to such a random hit point
is $$Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 \sim Chisq(2) = Exp(rate = 1/2),$$
which can be divided by $2$ to get a random variable $Q \sim Exp(rate = 1)$ with CDF $P(Q \le t) = F(t) = 1 - e^{-t},$ for $t > 0.$
Then it is easy to show that $e^{-Q} \sim Unif(0,1).$

So starting with two independent standard normal random variables,
we have found two standard uniform random variables (which turn out to be independent).
The Box-Muller transformation is the inverse of process.

Below is an illustration of the Box-Muller transform starting with
10,000 pairs of uniformly distributed points.

```
 m = 10000;  u1 = runif(m);  u2 = runif(m)
 z1 = sqrt(-2*log(u1))*cos(2*pi*u2)
 z2 = sqrt(-2*log(u1))*sin(2*pi*u2)
 mean(u1);  var(u1)
 ## 0.5006089    # approx 1/2
 ## 0.08388625   # approx 1/12
 mean(z1);  var(z1)
 ## -0.003667858 # approx 0
 ## 1.016240     # approx 1
 shapiro.test(z1[1:5000])  # Shapiro-Wilk test of normality

 ##   Shapiro-Wilk normality test

 ## data:  z1[1:5000]   # First 50000 (size limit for procedure)
 ## W = 0.9997, p-value = 0.6502  # consistent with normal
```

[image]

A second simulation uses 16 colors to illustrate the nature of the transformation. A point on the left-hand plot has the same color as its image under the Box-Muller transformation on the right. (A very small percentage of points lie outside the plotting region of the right-hand plot.)

[image]